# How to return all rows between 2 sections in a string in python 3.X?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file I'm reading into python, and I want to return just the three lines:

```
12151   2015-10-07 03:21:14.673
12319   2015-12-11 20:02:28.170
12327   2015-12-03 22:15:13.067
```

Below is an example piece of the file (i had to add $ characters that aren't in the file for it to show up correctly. those aren't in the file):

```
-

*******************Cell's that didn't call in*********************

CELL ID Last Call

------  ---------

12151   2015-10-07 03:21:14.673

12319   2015-12-11 20:02:28.170

12327   2015-12-03 22:15:13.067

-

****Cell's that didn't clear in the past 2 days****

CELL ID Cleared

------  -------

-

None
```

I've been trying to use `re.findall("'t call in*********************(.+?)**Cell's that didn't clear", file)`
where 'file' is the string of the whole file, but I keep running into issues. 
What is the best way to accomplish this without changing the format of the file itself?

Comment: Try using regular expressions to match your desired format

Comment: Why did you need to add the `$` characters? BTW, you have to be careful when trying to match `*` in a regex. Either put it in square brackets to make a character class, or escape it with a backslash. But you probably don't need regex for this.

Comment: it wouldn't display everything on separate lines before i did. sorry - first time posting question. i figured it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't parse files using regex. You need a parser. For what you are doing, some string matching is probably all you need.

```
extractedLines = []
extract = False
with open("./log.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Cell's that didn't clear in the past 2 days" in line:
            extract = False
        if extract:
            extractedLines.append(line)
        if "Cell's that didn't call in" in line:
            extract = True

print extractedLines
```

Notice how this is a bit hard to read (although nothing too horrible). 
If we want to make it more readable and we don't care about reading the file multiple times

```
def findLine(lines, text):
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if text in line:
            return i
    return None

with open("./log.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    startIndex = findLine(lines, "Cell's that didn't call in")
    endIndex   = findLine(lines, "Cell's that didn't clear in the past 2 days")

    extractedLines = [line for i,line in enumerate(f) if i>startIndex and i<endIndex]
```

Comment: thanks. only thing that didn't work was the print statement, because we need ()'s in 3.x